# SOAP signature is not valid

Tags: java, android, xml, soap

I have encountered on problem with SOAP signature. I am using Android 4.3. The server says that my signature is not valid. I got an [example](http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/CZ1212121218.valid.xml) message I am trying to recreate it. 
So what is the problem? I am trying generate SignatureValue from SignInfo.

if someone could explain to me teh whole process of creating the SOAP message with details I would be very glad. I have been seeking for an answer for too long.

My message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="X509-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005021" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005345"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod><ds:Reference URI="#id-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005214"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>UWKUBp8O/jI/pJyTxtsXC5Vz/bBwbz+XUyIODQpcN+E=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue></ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005082"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005123"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005021" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></wsse:Reference></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005214"><Trzba xmlns="http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/schema/v2"><Hlavicka dat_odesl="2016-09-19T19:06:37+01:00" prvni_zaslani="false" uuid_zpravy="9edeb22b-4234-4047-869c-3a76f86c20d3"></Hlavicka><Data celk_trzba="34113.00" cerp_zuct="679.00" cest_sluz="5460.00" dan1="-172.39" dan2="-530.73" dan3="975.65" dat_trzby="2016-01-05T00:30:12+01:00" dic_popl="CZ1212121218" id_pokl="/5546/RO24" id_provoz="273" porad_cis="0/6460/ZQ42" pouzit_zboz1="784.00" pouzit_zboz2="967.00" pouzit_zboz3="189.00" rezim="0" urceno_cerp_zuct="324.00" zakl_dan1="-820.92" zakl_dan2="-3538.20" zakl_dan3="9756.46" zakl_nepodl_dph="3036.00"></Data><KontrolniKody><pkp cipher="RSA2048" digest="SHA256" encoding="base64">lncmU7IdeWbscoTzTykEZ7NdATPtAH3t3i0mpNbAx3oquNJ7ML3UghGDDHncKLyfpnR+zCIltifxCx7k18X/9ZQVRMh5/42kTTPHlTR9x8y8i3zcK00+5znfgW/ofIT+mZUkJQ2dztxGmrVTJeYvXCrKX5qH+zwPpkdAAbc3DjhC+meMA8U+FY9MpqYZd0x7AzWSUI5gmrBxMThPZnzn3nonpFLwRI+WcGndnWzzLPf16CnJW3LJoYojGxzBC0peaEnDcWbr9WGeW+OFBv2MHrglip5RWugp+xat4g1jgWiMWyDA2TF6yY6ybtD1axygRfqqbmPMPKSX7Wl3xi4C3g==</pkp><bkp digest="SHA1" encoding="base16">F7370733-DF026DD5-704477C8-6AEA6E34-4CB34D92</bkp></KontrolniKody></Trzba></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

My SignInfo for getting Digest to sign

```
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-D674E7DD8DD86468D614642776005214"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>UWKUBp8O/jI/pJyTxtsXC5Vz/bBwbz+XUyIODQpcN+E=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo>
```

And there is my java code to generate the SignatureValue:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initSign(CertificateManager.getCustomersPrivateKey(context));
signature.update("".getBytes());
byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
String value = Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Android doesn't nativaly support SOAP messaging but I have to USE IT.

requirements:

1. The WS-Security 1.0 and XML Signature standards are used for the electronic signature
2. The X509 certificate belonging to the private key used to implement the electronic signature
   on the registered sale data message, including the SOAP envelope, shall be attached in the
   BinarySecurityToken element (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsssoap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary)
   in the X509v3 format (http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3)
3. The "Exclusive C14N" XML canonicalization algorithm shall be used (Exclusive XML
   Canonicalization Version 1.0, https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/)
4. To calculate the hash (digest) of the SOAP message's signature, the SHA256 algorithm shall
   be used (http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256)
5. For the SOAP message's electronic signature, the RSA-SHA256 algorithm shall be used
   (http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256)
6. The entire  element shall be included in the electronic signature, the message
   headers are not signed electronically (WS-Addressing or other standards requiring a similar
   concept are used)
7. Other requirements concerning WSS may be provided in the WSDL.

Complete documentation for the problem: [here](http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/EET_popis_rozhrani_v2.0_EN.pdf)

**Help is greatly appreciated!**